# Can I use Connector/Python instead of MySQLdb? And how?

Tags: django

I am using Python 3.3.1 and Django 1.5.1. MySQLdb doesn't support Python 3, so I want to use Connector/Python instead. But I don't know how to do this.

Is it easy to do this? If it is, how can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the mysql connector, and here is the guide to python developers:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/

You can also use MariaDB.

Answer (score 0):

You could use pymysql. "The goal of PyMySQL is to be a drop-in replacement for MySQLdb". Check the docs [here](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL).

> pip install mysqlclient pymysql

Once these libraries are installed, just add the lines in the `manage.py` file in your Django project and use the database settings for mysql.

> import pymysql
>
> pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()